# PHP Configuration Hostinger

Tags: php, wordpress, configuration, themes, hosting

I purchased a WordPress Theme from **themeforest.net**
and also I purchased WordPress hosting from **hostinger** without cPanel

When I install the template it appears
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5yfb.jpg)

Comment: You can contact hostinger they have excellent support team and reply almost instantly you may face 10-20 minutes delay now because of covid

Answer (score 0):

It shows the **System Requirements / System Status** of your existing WordPress installation. And the author suggests minimum requirements to run smoothly if it is below then it shows red dash which need to be sorted from your end.

You just need to contact your hosting provider and ask them to change the values accordingly if you are not about the panel configurations

Answer (score 0):

You purchased a shared hosting and in your hpanel you will found auto installer and there you will see wordpress, woocommerce, joomla and others. Select wordpress and install